# Boa tarde glr precisava de uma ajuda em um tipo de exercicio em SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

13. Liste as informações dos clientes que nasceram a partir de 1990. Exiba somente o nome e a
    data de nascimento, juntamente com a concatenação dos campos DDD e telefone, no formato
    (ddd) telefone'.

    SELECT Nome_Cliente         AS 'Nome do Cliente',
    Data_de_Nascimento   AS 'Data de Nascimento',
    DDD_Cliente          AS 'DDD Telefone',
    Telefone_Cliente     AS 'Telefone'
    WHERE DDD_Clientes INNER JOIN Telefone_Clientes
    Data_de_Nascimento YEAR >= '1990'
    FROM CLIENTES
    GO

fiz este codigo mais nao esta conseguindo roda ele diz dar erro oque esta de errado nele

ESTA E A TABELA QUE EU PRECISAVA FILTRAR A DATA DE NASCIMENTO E JUNTAR O DDD COM O TELEFONE
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htIeS.png)

Comment: Year(Data_de_Nascimento) >= 1990

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, meu brother! Tenta dar uma melhorada na estrutura das suas querys, as condições não estão nos lugares corretos, acredito que esteja iniciando com sql server. Não entendi muito bem a sua questão, mas acredito ser algo parecido com isso que esteja procurando:

```
SELECT 
    NOME_CLIENTE AS 'NOME_CLIENTE', 
    DATA_DE_NASCIMENTO AS 'DATA_NASCIMENTO',
    CONCAT( DDD, TELEFONE_CLIENTE ) AS 'DDD_TELEFONE'
FROM CLIENTES AS A 
    INNER JOIN TELEFONE_CLIENTES AS B
    ON A.NOME_CLIENTE = B.NOME_CLIENTE
WHERE YEAR(DATA_DE_NASCIMENTO) >= '1990'
```